# How to create new commit rather than fast-forward merging on GitKraken

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken

I am trying to learn GitKraken to manage my Git repo.
I want to merge some changes into a branch, 
on Sourcetree there is a "Create a new commit even if fast-forward is possible" [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G8cl.png) on the merge window:

And on GitKraken I just cannot find the equivalent option, 
when I right-clicked on the commit and clicked "Merge [branch1] into [branch2]," 
it just merged right away without a prompt.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe consider doing it from the command line with `git merge -n <branch>`

Comment: Got it, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the branch you wanna merge into current branch,

- Choose "Fast-forward branch1 into branch2" to do a fast-forward merge
- Choose "Merge branch1 into branch2" to do a non-fast-forward merge